# How to detect handling of image rotation by the browser engine version

Tags: cross-browser, webkit, exif

I need to properly display an image depending on it exif image orientation tag.
I adjusted the rotation and flipping of the image for each case in the 8 possible image orientation options (described [here](https://exceptionshub.com/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images.html))
I tested on the images in [here](https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples)
In Chrome (version 81.0) on Ubuntu 18.04, all image options display properly.

On MacOS and iOS I get different behaviors. Sometimes the images are not displayed properly
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390195/exif-orientation-issue-in-safari-mobile) that the behavior may change depending on the version of the webkit browser engine.

I want to adjust the code to each use case:

- browser (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari)
- engine version (e.g. webkit version < 13.4, webkit version >= 13.4, etc...)

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) and [here](https://code-boxx.com/detect-browser-with-javascript/) that detecting the user agent is usually a bad idea, and that it is better to detect the existence of the feature

In my case, the feature exists in the different versions but the behavior of the agent is different between versions? (I think)

**What would be the best way to detect the handling of image orientation (handling of exif imageOrientation tag)**

Thanks,
Avner

Answer (score 2):

That is cased because the default value of `image-orientation` has been changed in the recent versions of browsers.

From Chrome 81, the default value is `from-image`. https://chromestatus.com/feature/6313474512650240

In iOS, I observed that the value is `from-image` from iOS 13.4.

And I use the following code to detect the default value.

```js
const getImageOrientation = (): string => {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  const imageOrientation = window.getComputedStyle(img).imageOrientation;
  document.body.removeChild(img);
  return imageOrientation;
};

if (getImageOrientation() !== 'from-image') {
  // rotate image
}
```